# Do you need to fence in your animals?

Tags: stardew-valley

Is there and reason to build fences around your animals? I've seen several people raising free-range chickens. Are there any disadvantages to raising chickens free-range? What about the other animals? Can I just have an open ranch, or does it not work that way?

Comment: Free-range means that the chickens aren't kept inside in cages all the time. Fenced in chickens are free-range chickens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having an open ranch is fine, you aren't penalized for letting your animals be free-range. There are some problems with specific livestock that make it more sensible to fence them in however.

Pigs, for example, dig up truffles on the farm. If you don't fence your animals in, the truffles *could* be anywhere on your farmland, meaning you have to spend quite a bit of time to search for them. Fencing them in means you have a smaller area to search for those truffles.